# How do I create an Outlook add-in that alerts the user when they attempt to reply to senders that are outside of their domain?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am new to coding in c#. I am currently trying to create an Outlook add-in to prompt and alert users if they are to attempt to reply to anyone that is not from "@abc.com". For example if 'ben@abc.com' is to trying to reply to 'jack@def.com', a window to alert Ben will be prompted warning him "You are about to reply to someone that is not from '@abc.com'." with the options of 'ok' and 'cancel'.

I referred online for the code below but this add-in only allows me to edit the field values of the email I am trying to send. I am unable to even figure out how to address and implement the code to deal with replying. I have tried researching online and have seen methods like .reply() but  I am confused as to how to apply them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace FirstOutlookAddIn
{

    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

        Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
            inspectors.NewInspector +=
            new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
        }


        void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
                {
                    mailItem.To = "Testing for Recipient.";
                    mailItem.Subject = "Currently testing add-in for Subject.";
                    mailItem.Body = "Currently testing add-in for Body.";
                    mailItem.CC = "Testing for CC.";
                }

            }

        }

            private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
            //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
    
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are only tracking `Inspectors.NewInspector` event. But in most cases replies will be inline - you also need `Explorer.InlineResponse` event (where `Explorer` comes from `Application.ActiveExplorer`, which can be null on startup, so you'd also need `Application.Explorers.NewExplorer` event).

Secondly, you will need to loop through all recipients in the `mailItem.Recipients` collection, and for each `Recipient`, check the `Recipient.Address` property (which you can test for the match).

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `send` `event`, as it will be triggered irrespective of `inline` replies or `inspector` level replies.

```
this.Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
```

then implementation of this can be done as below,

```
/// param : item -> mail item to be sent
/// param : cancel -> allows you to cancel sending mail in outlook. By default value is false. 
private void Application_ItemSend(object item, ref bool cancel){
   Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
   // read "mail.To" and check for your logic; 
   // if To list has other domains, then show the warning prompt maybe like below,
   var result = MessageBox.Show("yourmessage","title",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
   if(result == DialogResult.No)
     cancel = true; // setting this to `true` will stop sending an email out.
}
```

you can read on this event in MS blog here [Item_Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend)